# Looping through arrays within an array, if particular array has a specific word, grab that array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm trying to create a search function where a search word is passed through (for example, "Food" or "Gym") and the function will loop through the arrays in the array, if that word is found within a nested array, it will be push that exact array into a filtered array. Which I can then display to the user.

I've tried looking at different solutions but no luck. This is what I have so far.

```
 // Filter list with search keyword
    function filter(keyword,list) {
      // placeholder for matches
      var filtered = [];
      // loop through list
      for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        var store = list[i];

        // loop through each individual array/store in list
        for (var y = 0; y < store.length; y++) {
        // if match keyword
        if(store[y].match(keyword)){
          // push that store into filtered array
                filtered.push(store);
          }

      else{
        alert('cannot find');
      };    
     };
  };    
};     



var list=[
    ["Mikes Gym",
    "21 Rosenberg Road",
    "Heidelberg",
    "Come get your ice",
    "5",
    ["onsequat. Phasellus diam .", "malesuada in. Integer eget molestie mi. Etiam a"],
    "9104-1059",
    "Gym"
    ],
      ["Mikes Cafe",
    "21 Rosenberg Road",
    "Heidelberg",
    "Come get your ice",
    "5",
    ["onsequat. Phasellus diam .", "malesuada in. Integer eget molestie mi. Etiam a"],
    "9104-1059",
     "Food"
    ],
      ["Mikes Hairdresser",
    "21 Rosenberg Road",
    "Heidelberg",
    "Come get your ice",
    "5",
    ["onsequat. Phasellus diam .", "malesuada in. Integer eget molestie mi. Etiam a"],
    "9104-1059",
     "Hairdresser"
    ],
      ["Mikes Nightclub",
    "21 Rosenberg Road",
    "Heidelberg",
    "Come get your ice",
    "5",
    ["onsequat. Phasellus diam .", "malesuada in. Integer eget molestie mi. Etiam a"],
    "9104-1059",
     "Club"
    ],
      ["Mikes Groceries",
    "21 Rosenberg Road",
    "Heidelberg",
    "Come get your ice",
    "5",
    ["onsequat. Phasellus diam .", "malesuada in. Integer eget molestie mi. Etiam a"],
    "9104-1059",
     "Shop"
    ]
  ];

filter("Food",list)
```

Comment: I think your main problem resides in the use of `.match()`. It's meant to be used with a regular expression. Are you sure you're using it properly ? Futhermore, I'd rather use map/filter/reduce functions for those scenarii rather the for loops.

Comment: Right! I didn't think of filter and map. Sorry, I'm still new and this is my first time creating something from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not exactly clear. Is this what you need? It returns the nearest array that contains the matching word.
I used RegExp test to find the matching word, if you need to find the exact words, use === instead since test is not as performant. I only put there since you can write some more versatile random RegExp with it.

```
function wordFilter(keyword, list) {

  var filter = [];

  recursiveFilter(keyword, list);

  function recursiveFilter(keyword, list) {
      //Loop if list is array, otherwise test if it matches the keyword
      if(Array.isArray(list)) {

        for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

            if(recursiveFilter(keyword, list[i])) {
                //This unlikely to return true, I just put it there to make sure
                if(Array.isArray(list[i])){
                    filter.push(list[i]);
                } else {
                    filter.push(list);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
      } else {
        var reg = new RegExp(keyword);
        return reg.test(list);
      }
   }
   return filter;
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thank you so much. I am now going to throw that in the debugger and see what exactly is going on. Appreciate it. :)

Comment: Please mark this as correct answer if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
function wordFilter(list, keyword) {
    var returnVal;
    list.forEach(function(childList) {
        childList.foreach(function(value) {
            if (value === keyword) {
                returnVal = childList;
            }
        })
    });
    return returnVal;
}

console.log(wordFilter([["test", "monkeys"], ["car", "airplane"]], "test"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     // Filter list with search keyword
    function filter(keyword,list) {
      // placeholder for matches
      var filtered = [];
      // loop through list
      for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      var store=list[i];
        for (var y = 0; y < store.length; y++) {
        // if match keyword
        if(store[y]==keyword){
          // push that store into filtered array
                filtered.push(list[i]);
          }
      } 
    }
   return filtered;
    }    `
```

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up of my comment, here is a sample code using `indexOf()` instead of `match()` in order to know if a string contains a substring. I'll also use `filter()` and `join()` instead of two for loops.

```
var findIn = function findIn(needle, haystack) {
        return haystack.filter(function(el) {
            return el.join(' ').indexOf(needle) > -1;
        });
    }
  , list = ["Mikes Gym", "21 Rosenberg Road", "Heidelberg", "Come get your ice", "5", ["onsequat. Phasellus diam .", "malesuada in. Integer eget molestie mi. Etiam a"], "9104-1059", "Gym" ], ["Mikes Cafe", "21 Rosenberg Road", "Heidelberg", "Come get your ice", "5", ["onsequat. Phasellus diam .", "malesuada in. Integer eget molestie mi. Etiam a"], "9104-1059", "Food" ], ["Mikes Hairdresser", "21 Rosenberg Road", "Heidelberg", "Come get your ice", "5", ["onsequat. Phasellus diam .", "malesuada in. Integer eget molestie mi. Etiam a"], "9104-1059", "Hairdresser" ], ["Mikes Nightclub", "21 Rosenberg Road", "Heidelberg", "Come get your ice", "5", ["onsequat. Phasellus diam .", "malesuada in. Integer eget molestie mi. Etiam a"], "9104-1059", "Club" ], ["Mikes Groceries", "21 Rosenberg Road", "Heidelberg", "Come get your ice", "5", ["onsequat. Phasellus diam .", "malesuada in. Integer eget molestie mi. Etiam a"], "9104-1059", "Shop" ] ]
  ;

console.log(findIn("Food",list));
```

The conditional part, `return el.join(' ').indexOf(needle) > -1;`, might be adapted to your needs, using lower case match only, regular expression or any other method that will return a boolean.